# MS access single form to add records in another table

Tags: database, forms, ms-access

So there is three tables:

- Performer Table: Performer ID (1), Performer Name, (Other Performer
  Details)
- Round Table: Round Number (1) , Round Date, Round    Description
- Vote Table: Rounder Number (∞) , Performer ID (∞), Number    of Votes

I gave a ICT practical exam yesterday and was asked to create a single form without any subforms that will allow the input of votes for each round, where,

- The Round Number must be shown only once.
- The Names of the Performers must be displayed in ascending order
- The ability to input votes for all acts on that same form
- Calculate the total votes in that round

Can anyone tell me how this could be done without the help of a subform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be easier in this case to prepopulate the Vote table with each round and every performer and set the vote count to 0.  That way you could display the form and filter for a particular round, then show all performers with a box to input votes.  You could do a sum to display the total votes for that round in the header or footer.

Would this work for you?

Comment: My vote table already contained all the round numbers and the performer IDs with vote count to 0. But I don't understand how I can show all the records for each round in a form. The only solution i could come up with was this, https://support.content.office.net/en-us/media/8d712f52-0c4e-4a04-9ffa-7c04cfd75905.jpg Where in 1, the round details is displayed, and in 2 all the performer of that particular round and their votes was shown...

Comment: but how can i do something similar without the subform?

Comment: Take a look at this solution under the section labeled Main Form (no subform) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19199973/filtering-microsoft-access-records-based-on-combo-box-predefined-values.  Basically you will need a drop-down at the top of your form listing the possible rounds, then in code it will filter the form.  Let me know if this helps.